# How do we assign object into `UINavigationController` without pushing a ViewController object into it.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

How do we assign object into `UINavigationController` without pushing a `ViewController` object into it.
Why do I need it is here :

I have total three `Segment views` and one of the segment is this that I am adding as `subView` :

```
-(void)Frds{
    [self clearSubView];
    obj = [[Frds alloc]initWithNibName:@"Frds" bundle:nil];
    [obj.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 65, 320, 568)];
    [self.view addSubview:obj.view];
}
```

and from `Frds` class when I access `self.navigationController`. It returns me `nil`, and it should obviously since I have not pushed the `ViewController` into it.

So, What is the way to access `navigationController` in `Frds` class after adding 'Frds' class object view as a 'subview' from forwarding class.

Comment: Why not just set the obj.navigationController after you instantiate it?

Comment: because I have to add it as subview on my initial view. with custom Y and sometimes custom width and height too.

Comment: Is the current view controller ('self' in your code above) contained within the navigation controller?

Comment: So, after you init `obj`, just execute `obj.navigationController=self.navigationController;`

Comment: dude navigationController is a readonly property. You can't assign it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65797/discussion-between-paulw11-and-user3693546).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your **frnd** View object on **rootviewController** view object . First assign one **rootviewcontroller** on your navigation controller then you can easily add your view on it .

For assigning root view controller on navigation controller :

```
UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];
```

Use this method to find your root view controller:

```
UIViewController *rootViewController = self.navigationController.viewControllers[0];
```

Comment: rootViewController will return your base  view controller : Now you can add your friend view on it like : [rootViewController.view addSubview frnd]